# yum/curl failing to retrieve from an IPv6 repo: 400 bad request

Tags: curl, ipv6, yum

Yum is failing to retrieve packages from a repo with an IPv6 address:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

The problem is reproduceable using curl.

With curl, a workaround is to add the `--globoff` parameter.

However there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to do that using yum.
Yum doesn't have a `--globoff` parameter, nor any obvious way to pass arbitrary parameters to curl.

Apparently, there is a bug fix in recent versions of yum (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1076277), to automagically add the globoff parameter when calling curl, but it seems not to be happening here for some reason (Possibly that my version of yum is just a little too old. But even if that would work, upgrading yum isn't an ideal option for various reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem only happens if the hostname is used in the baseurl, does not happen if the IPv6 address is used.

This doesn't work:

```
[rpm_server]
name=RPM repository
baseurl=http://<hostname>/repo/rh7.7/
```

This works:

```
[rpm_server]
name=RPM repository
baseurl=http://<IPv6 address>/repo/rh7.7/
```

Speculation, but perhaps explicitly putting the IPv6 address instead of the host name allows yum to realise that it is dealing with an IPv6 host and pass `--globoff` to curl.